# How to print barcode using tsc ttp-244 pro printer in php

Tags: php

I am doing barcode printing label application. I'm using tsc ttp-244 pro printer. How to write the `php` code for barcode label to send print to printer?

Please help to solve this issue.

Please check the code below
    open printer

```
<?php

$handle = printer_open('TSC TTP-244 Pro'); //or it could be  


//set printing option to raw
printer_set_option($handle, PRINTER_MODE, 'RAW');
 printer_set_option($handle, PRINTER_COPIES, '1');

 //write data to printer
$esc = chr(27);
$data = '';
$data .= $esc . 'A';
$data .= $esc . 'A3H1374V0001';
$data .= $esc . 'H0050' . $esc . 'V0100' . $esc . 'L0303' . $esc . 'XMSATO';
$data .= $esc . 'H0050' . $esc . 'V0200' . $esc . 'B103100*SATO*';
$data .= $esc . 'H0170' . $esc . 'V0310' . $esc . 'L0101' . $esc . 'XUSATO';
$data .= $esc . 'Q1';
$data .= $esc . 'Z';


$ret = printer_write($handle, $data);
//close the printer handle
printer_close($handle);

?>
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on example on https://github.com/leesaw/pradit/blob/b91513e3978e75610a0bbd06cfa4751fb3702f16/tsc/printbarcode.php

You should study this code https://github.com/leesaw/pradit/tree/b91513e3978e75610a0bbd06cfa4751fb3702f16

```
          $TSCObj  = new COM ("TSCActiveX.TSCLIB") or die("Unable to open COM object");
          $TSCObj->ActiveXopenport("TSC TTP-244 Plus");           
          //$TSCObj->ActiveXdownloadpcx("C:/xampp/htdocs/pradit/tsc/logo.pcx","logo.pcx");
          $TSCObj->ActiveXsetup("104", "52", "3", "10", "0", "2", "0");
          //$TSCObj->ActiveXformfeed();
          //$TSCObj->ActiveXsendcommand("HOME");
          //$TSCObj->ActiveXsendcommand("SET TEAR OFF");
          $TSCObj->ActiveXclearbuffer();
          //$TSCObj->ActiveXsendcommand("PUTPCX 300,250,\"logo.pcx\"");

          // print product name
          $name1 = iconv("UTF-8", "TIS-620", $_GET['name']);
          $TSCObj->ActiveXwindowsfont(60, 50, 54, 0, 2, 0, "Angsana New", $name1);
          $TSCObj->ActiveXwindowsfont(450, 50, 54, 0, 2, 0, "Angsana New", $name1);

          // print product price + vat
          $price1 = "ÃÒ¤Ò ".number_format($_GET['price'], 2, '.', ',')." ºÒ·";
          $TSCObj->ActiveXwindowsfont(60, 330, 54, 0, 2, 0, "Angsana New", $price1);
          $TSCObj->ActiveXwindowsfont(450, 330, 54, 0, 2, 0, "Angsana New", $price1);

          // print barcode
          $TSCObj->ActiveXbarcode("60", "110", "128", "200", "1", "0", "2", "2", $_GET['bc']);  
          $TSCObj->ActiveXbarcode("450", "110", "128", "200", "1", "0", "2", "2", $_GET['bc']); 

          // print number of copies
          $copy = ceil($_GET["copy"]/2);
          if ($copy > 0) {
            for ($i=0; $i<$copy; $i++) {
                $TSCObj->ActiveXprintlabel("1","1");
            }
            echo "Printing....";
          }else{
            echo "Error!!!";
          }
          //$TSCObj->ActiveXformfeed();
          $TSCObj->ActiveXcloseport();
```

Comment: i have written the code like this. but it is not printing the barcode label

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84926/pasting-code-into-stackoverflow-question-textbox

Comment: I have updated my post, you should use COM class for it. not printer_open

Comment: ya , i have used your code. but getting exception error

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message 'Failed to create COM object `TSCActiveX.TSCLIB': C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\barcode_printing\printbarcode.php on line 3

Comment: Do you download driver TSCActiveX.TSCLIB for it?

Comment: http://en.pudn.com/downloads421/sourcecode/windows/detail1783631_en.html

Comment: hi mishanon, i  have created account and it is asking to upload 5 source codes. please help me